# Socket-io disconnection on Logout and network out

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there any way to trigger socket-io disconnect on user logout and networkout. For now it only works when browser is closed. Check Heart Beat is one solution but is there any other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.disconnect() can be called from the frontend. Not sure about the network out though. i think there should be network out method at frontend which will trigger socket.reconnect once connection is restored